# How to get data from QueryDict?

Tags: django, django-errors

I have this data from forms

```
<QueryDict: {
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['GKVYyp5MZHM39C4UJU13YOqCr5euox35X6xy19L87FhKwQY7UiT9nQYBpnNm7ZSt', 
                             'GKVYyp5MZHM39C4UJU13YOqCr5euox35X6xy19L87FhKwQY7UiT9nQYBpnNm7ZSt', 
                             'GKVYyp5MZHM39C4UJU13YOqCr5euox35X6xy19L87FhKwQY7UiT9nQYBpnNm7ZSt', 
                             'GKVYyp5MZHM39C4UJU13YOqCr5euox35X6xy19L87FhKwQY7UiT9nQYBpnNm7ZSt'], 
     'User': ['11', '11', '12', '13'], 
     'month': ['march', 'march', 'february', 'july'], 
     'regularFee': ['1500', '988', '7656', '7000'], 
     'extraFee': ['0', '0', '23', '7'], 
     'discount': ['234', '0', '0', '7'], 
     'Total': ['1500', '987', '1500', '7000']}>
```

can anyone please tell me how to extract data from this
I want a new dictionary which will have index as key and value will be another dictionary of data, which will include information of each user

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    keys = []
    length = 0

    for key in request.POST.keys():
        keys.append(key)
        length = len(request.POST[key])

    for index in range(length):
        dict_messForm = {}
        for key in keys:
            dict_messForm.update({key:request.POST[key][index]})
        forms.append(messFeeForm(dict_messForm))
```

this is giving me an error 'string index out of range'......
how can I create forms from this QueryDict ?

Comment: If you share the traceback, we can more easily see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

QueryDict is fetched using getlist menthod.

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
    keys = []
    length = 0
    for key in request.POST.keys():
        keys.append(key)
        length = len(request.POST[key])
    length = length - 1
    for index in range(length):
        dict_messForm = {}
        for key in keys:
            l = list(request.POST.getlist(key))
            value = l[index]
            dict_messForm.update({key:value})
        forms.append(messFeeForm(dict_messForm))
```